# javascript setInterval json request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, setinterval

Below is the JavaScript code where it should count every 1 min but somehow counting every 20 seconds.

```
var tim = setInterval(doCount, 60000);
var count = 0;
var currency = "R$";
var stopit = 0;
function doCount() {
   stopit++;
   if (stopit > 30) {
      $.ajax({
         url: "URL",
         cache: false,
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (json) {
            $.get("URL");
         },
         error: function (e, xhr) {

         }
      });
      return false;
   }
   count += 1.99;
   $("#number").html(
      currency +  parseFloat(count).toFixed(2).replace(/\./g, ',')
   );
   $.post("URL"});
}
```

Comment: Tried pasting your code into JSFIDDLE, seems to work once every minute here.. http://jsfiddle.net/w72R5/  :(

Comment: Which browser did you use? Did you cross-test it in another browser?

Comment: it does actually count in my development box as expected but in live server it doesn't.do you think the problem server setup or client side? also chekced cross-test

Comment: I do not know, if the server calls influence the behaviour of the `setInterval` method, if the call fails. Can you check if the ajax calls pass? Also try to add `return true` to the end of your `doCount()` method, maybe that might be missing

Comment: btw: check your browser cache ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give you an alternative - have a look at the `jquery` plugin [doTimeout](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/)

Especially have a look at the [polling examples](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-dotimeout/examples/delay-poll/)

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the doCount inside a function like this

```
var tim = setInterval(function() {
      doCount();
}, 60000);
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question well, you just have to change 60000 miliseconds to 20000. (20 sec)

```
var tim = setInterval(doCount, 20000);
```

Comment: It is already counting for 20 secs and the expected is for 60 sec which is 1 min.